# Are source code is added with APK taken from Android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, apk

Does source code are included with the APK taken from Android studio?

if yes how can we remove it so that users can't access the source code anytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code is not added into APK, but bytecode of APK can be decoded into java code.

You can use proguard to shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app and it's hard to read when decoded.

Here are example of using proguard (put it into build.gradle)

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```